# Is there any way to prevent my application from running on Windows 7 machines?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

As suggested in the title, I've created an application (windows forms) on Visual Express 2010 on a machine using Windows XP. I've tested the application on a machine running Windows 7 and the format change of buttons and controls kind of ruin the general look of the application.

Is there any way to prevent my application from running on a Windows 7 computer?

Other alternative would be checking what OS is the user using and depending on this, change the alignment/position of buttons/controls/etc...

What would be the best approach?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What makes you think your application looks the same on all WinXP systems, regardless of theme settings? I would be very surprised if the exact same problem is not reproducible on XP (possibly by installing third-party themes).

Comment: Do you *really* want to only allow people with a (semi)obsolete operating system to run your program?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Based on the question, Windows 8 is okay. :)

Comment: The best approach would be to make your UI OS-independent. Second best would be to fix it for Windows 7. Supporting XP doesn't make sense anymore nowadays.

Comment: This is an app for a specific set of users which only run XP computers (if it were up to me, they wouldn't be running XP, believe me :]). At some point their machines will be upgraded to Windows 7, and then I will just make a "port" of the app on a Windows 7 so that it also looks OK in Windows 7. As I've said, it's just a matter of design and looks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply check what operating system version your app is running on, if your program is running on windows 7 then exit the program, example,

```
if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().Contains("Microsoft Windows NT 6.1"))
{
    //code to execute if running win 7
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Sam! I think I will just check that and then change the position of buttons/controls/etc...

Comment: Your welcome. You could try using WPF instead, it [automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742562.aspx#graphics_and_rendering) takes dpi into account.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283), but the best approach is to make your application run and look correctly on Windows 7 too, you don't really want to lose the clients that have Windows 7 (especially now when that is the most used Windows version)

Answer (score 4):

You almost certainly mis-identified the source of the problem.  By far the most common cause of form layout corruption is the video adapter's DPI setting.  It determines the number of pixels per inch and is *very* easy to change on Windows 7.  It can also be changed on XP, it is just harder to do so.  The setting is a big deal, monitors are getting better especially with the Apple's push for "retina" displays.

Add the checking code by tweaking your Main() method in Program.cs.  Make it look similar to this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var main = new Form1();
        using (var gr = main.CreateGraphics()) {
            if (gr.DpiX != 96) {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, didn't get this done yet.  Bye");
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
        }
        Application.Run(main);
    }
```

Fixing your form layout is of course the long term solution.  The standard mistake is to give controls their own Font property that doesn't match the form's Font property or their container's.  An easy way to trigger the same problem on your XP machine is to emulate what the DPI setting does.  Saves you the hassle of finding the setting on XP and having to reboot the machine when you change it.  Paste this code into your form:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        this.Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily, this.Font.SizeInPoints * 120f / 96f);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Which is equivalent to selecting 125% scaling in the Win7 Display preferences.

Comment: Thank you for that Hans, I will try to do it that way.